# How To Render Java Graphics in a 2D game correctly and efficiently

Tags: java, 2d, rendering

I'm looking for an efficient way to implement 2D game rendering.

Here is an example of what kind of rendering system my game uses at the moment. (I either don't know how to use it or it's not flexible enough.)

I use Canvas and its BufferStrategies but I'm not sure how efficient they are.
Any help is appreciated.

```
//MY RENDERING SYSTEM EXPLAINED IN JAVA AND WITH ONLY ONE CLASS.
//DOES NOT INCLUDE TICKING JUST RENDERING, TICKING IS A DIFFERENT THREAD.
//(so they can run on different frames per second)
//main() method is at the very bottom.

/*
 * @Author
 *  CodyOrr4
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;


public class Main implements Runnable {

    public static Cache cache;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    public static JViewport camera;
    public static Canvas canvas;
    public static BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    public static Graphics graphics;
    public static boolean rendering = false;
    public static Thread renderingThread;

    //turns this runnable into an object.
    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame("Rendering System Example");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2000, 2000));

        cache = new Cache();

        panel.add(canvas);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    //used to run things that are not meant to be run in a loop;
    private void init() {
        cache.initCache(); //can now grab sprites (including names/ids) and other types within cache.
    }

    //renders everything (this method is used in a while() loop based on a boolean, within the run() method);
    private void render(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(cache.getSprite(0), 400, 300, 25, 25, null);

    }

    //runs the runnable
    public void run() {
        init();
        while(rendering) {
            setFps(16);//simply set fps now - iJustin   *codys note on the setFps(fps); method* = not sure if its the same thing lol, 
                                                        //but since ticking and rendering are separate threads in the main source (and contain separate init() methods) it seems like it would be good.

            if(bufferStrategy == null) {
                canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);//should only need a max of 3.
                bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
                graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
                System.out.println("creating canvas components...");
            }

            //drawing with methods
            render(graphics);

            //drawing without methods
            graphics.drawImage(cache.getSprite(0), 0, 0, 50, 50, null);



            bufferStrategy.show();
            graphics.dispose();
        }
    }

    //starts the run method and creates a thread for this 
    public synchronized void start() {
        renderingThread = new Thread(this);
        renderingThread.setName("Game Rendering Thread");
        renderingThread.start();
        rendering = true;
    }

    //stops the while loop by setting the boolean to false and the thread is now null
    public synchronized void stop() {
        renderingThread = null;
        rendering = false;
    }

    //@Author iJustin - sets fps of the rendering loop (while() loop within run() method)
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void setFps(long fps) {
        try {
            renderingThread.sleep(fps);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    //main method obv.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main gameExample = new Main();
        gameExample.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the fps, because rendering an image cannot take exactly always the same time, you should wait taking account the last rendering time

Comment: thats a pretty smart idea, how exactly would i go about doing that?

Comment: even though the setFps() method is used in the rendering loop to create 16 milisecond delay which allows 60 frames per 1000 milliseconds (almost) or 60 frames per second

Comment: the easier is to use Time class [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long) or simply measure the time by using System.nanoTime

Comment: ah, forgot about System.nanoTime for 'now' and 'lastTime' integers

Comment: why forgot nanoTime ?

Comment: Just never really understood its function, but ive used it in game loops before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fps, you should take in account the duration of the last frame rendering time
It allows to have constant frame rate

For this, you can, for each frame :

```
//a the start of rendering process
long startRendering=System.nanoTime();

... rendering here...

//duration of the frame rendering in ms :
long durationMs=TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime()-startRendering);

// now waits 
if (durationMs < fps) 
{
renderingThread.sleep(fps - durationMs);
}
```

System.nanoTime allows to measure time with a good accuracy : if you take the difference between two calls of System.nanoTime(), you have the time elapsed between the calls in nanoseconds.
I sugest to not use System.currentTimeMillis which is less accurate

Comment: Wow nice, thanks alot and i would set the variable 'fps' to 60 to render at 60 frames per second right?

Comment: No, your fps variable was in ms so if you want 60 frames per secondes : fps = 1000 / 60